# Python exception "too many vaues to unpack" thrown when assigning a string of numbers to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function that reads a file which contains a name followed by a space, then multiple numbers, each seperated by a space. I want to parse the name into one string, and all the numbers into another, then put them in a dictionary (with the name as the key). I have written the following code:

```
def read_users (user_file):
    try:
        file_in = open(user_file)
    except:
        return None
    user_scores = {}
    for line in file_in:
        temp_lst = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        user_scores = [temp_lst[0]] = temp_lst[1]
    return user_scores
```

This seems to do everything I need, but when it puts it into a dictionary it throws the exception "Too many values to unpack". I'm confused as to why this is thrown because I think I should be passing the dictionary a string with the name as the key, and a string with a bunch of numbers as the value. 
If it's important the lines in the input file are formatted as follows:

Ben 1 0 2 3 4 -2 5 5 6 6 1

I have tried printing the list before I pass it to the dictionary and it appears as follows:

['Ben', '1 0 2 3 4 -1 5 5 6 6 1']

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: user_scores[temp_lst[0]] = temp_lst[1]

Comment: incorrect way to make dictionary. You're making an array of length 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#I think the way you construct the dictionary is not quite right. Try below code to see if it works.
user_scores[temp_lst[0]] = temp_lst[1]
```

Comment: Doh! Yeah, that was the issue. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Please accept it as the answer so that other people will not click and try to answer this again.